# How to create a regex for -90 to -90 string acceptance?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
(^-?[0-9][0-9]{0,1}$)|(^-?90$)
```

this is what I've been able to create till now, it still fails in my unit tests.
What should be the correct one?

Edit: In this problem above -99 was getting accepted and 9 was not getting accepted.

Edit: I had been trying to accept -90 t0 90 in string format as I was getting the same from the server. Through the comments posted below it clicked to me that I was doing it all wrong, so I converted it to integer and used simple javascript comparison operators to solve my problem.

Comment: convert your strings to numbers and and test them with real code, this is an javascript regular expressions are not going to be able to do this without extensions

Comment: For doing numerical comparisons you are usually on much better footing in the app layer rather than relying on regex.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: @anshulix: Please post your unit tests along with this so that we know *what* your expectations are (and which of them failed).

Comment: I get it I should have been converting string to number, did in a wrong way. thanks @Jarrod. :)

Comment: @Bergi 9 was not getting accepted and +90 were getting accepted. anyway i got it right by converting to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For this simple if will sufficient, instead of going to REGEX

```
if(num >= -90 ||  num <= 90)  {
   //valid
}
```

Or if its hard and fast, following regex should work Provided by **@Stribizhev**:

```
^-?0*(?:[0-8]?[0-9]|90)$
```

Comment: Only that the regex doesn't work. Still accepts `99` for example.

Comment: Yes your regex doesn't work, but the other solution was bang on! Thanks

Comment: @anshulix what is missing on regex?

Comment: I believe it should be [`^-?0*(?:[0-8]?[0-9]|90)$`](https://regex101.com/r/oQ5pT7/1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make few edits to your regex it should accept 9 and you need to make change in first part. try this:

```
/(^-?[0-8][0-9]{0,1}$)|(^-?90$)|(^-?9$)/
```

this is the correct regex

Comment: This is not accepting `0099`. I don't know this is one of the case to consider.

Comment: You can simplify this to `^-?([0-8]?\d|90)$`

Comment: Yes, you are right but i don't think so it is required here.